# Submit button and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was told by someone on this site that it was best not to write inline function calls in your HTML when doing jQuery.  It sounds like a good plan.

So using jQuery, how do I call a function upon a button submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean *form* submission. And you can do it by binding an `onsubmit` event handler to your form:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, there are 2 different events you might want to use.

If you want to capture the button click, then you want the ["click" event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) of the button

If you want the form submit, then you want ["submit" event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of the form.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('form[name=myForm]').submit(function(){

// function here

});
```

[jQuery docs on submit();](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

Others already answered on how to do a form submission, but if you mean you just want to click the button then you would want to use

```
$('input[name=myButton]').click()
```

[jQuery docs on click();](http://api.jquery.com/click/)